# Getting posts, FacebookResponse contains an empty body

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get posts from my Facebook page, where I'm is logged now, like this:

```
try {
  $response = $fb->get('/me/posts', $accessToken->getValue);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

var_dump($response->getDecodedBody());
```

`getDecodedBody` returns

> array (size=1)   'data' => 
>       array (size=0)
>         empty

Or like this

```
$json_object = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?&access_token=' . $accessToken->getValue());
$posts = json_decode($json_object);
var_dump($posts);
```

and I getting the same result.

**Update:**

I have created access token using javascript

```
    window.onload = function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
          if (response.authResponse) {
            //alert('You are logged in &amp; cookie set!');
            // Now you can redirect the user or do an AJAX request to
            // a PHP script that grabs the signed request from the cookie.
            location.href = 'http://localhost/FB/js-login.php';
          } else {
            alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
          }
        });
        return false;
      };
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '123450723574945',
      cookie: true, // This is important, it's not enabled by default
      version: 'v2.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

And got it in php

```
$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

`var_dump($accessToken)` result:

> object(Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken)[13]
>   protected 'value' =>
>   string 'EAABrvUukr0EBAH8yuJpQkhdkZCZBW' (length=207)
>   protected 'expiresAt' => 
>       object(DateTime)[15]
>         public 'date' => string '2017-06-08 16:00:00.000000' (length=26)
>         public 'timezone_type' => int 3
>         public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)

As I can see, `expiresAt` property conrains date less then now, but I don't have any errors messages.

Comment: What do you mean, _“where I'm is logged now”_? What type of access token are you using, and what permissions does it contain?

Comment: @CBroe I have added details about access token in my question.

Comment: So you did not ask the user for _any_ permissions during login ...

Comment: Probably not, how I can do it?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Comment: I requested permission from the user the first time I logged in.

Comment: And what permission was that? Have you debugged the access token to verify it actually includes the permission?

Comment: I placed output  of var_dump($accessToken) in the start question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146184/discussion-between-evgeny-s-and-cbroe).

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/